# Can't Install Ubuntu 16.04 on QEMU/KVM: Failed to load ldlinux.c32

Tags: 16.04, kvm-virtualization

I'm trying to install 32-bit Ubuntu 16.04 which I download from [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/). I keep getting the same error, Failed to load ldlinux.c32 [Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rp8F.png). However, I tried to install the 64-bit version of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and able to install it successfully. Any help regarding this? Thank you.

N.B: In the host, I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver)

Comment: I'm not quite sure that I understood what you are referring to, I'm not using any USB stick to boot the OS. I put my .iso file inside **/var/lib/libvirt/images** .

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need the 32-bit version?

Comment: @ajgringo619 Yes, I need that 32-bit version for research purposes.